# Trouble passing arguments with Openai function agent in Langchain

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, agent, langchain

I am trying to make an agent using the Langchain framework. My goal is to create an agent that places orders to a store for me. The function/Tool I am using to place the order needs multiple inputs to run. I keep getting this error `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given`

```
from placeorder import order_three
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional, Type
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain.tools import BaseTool
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent, Tool


class order_three(BaseModel):
    """Place an order"""
first_name: str =Field(...,description= "The first name of person placing the order")
last_name: str =Field(...,description= "The last name of person placing the order")
phone_number: str =Field(...,description= "The phone number  of person placing the order")
product: str =Field(...,description= "The product they want to buy")
date_of_birth: str =Field(...,description= "The date of birth of person placing the order")
quantity: str =Field(...,description= "The amount of the product they want to buy")

class order_three(BaseTool):
name = "place_order"
description = "Useful when the user wants to place an order. You should input the firstname, lastname, quantity, product, date of birth, and phone number"

def _run(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, quantity: str, date_of_birth: str, product: str, phone_number: str):
place_order_response = order_three(first_name, last_name, phone_number, date_of_birth, product, quantity)

return place_order_response

def _arun(self, first_name: str, last_name: str, quantity: str, date_of_birth: str, product: str, phone_number: str):
raise NotImplementedError("This tool does not support async")

args_schema: Optional[Type[BaseModel]] = order_three


tools = [order_three()]

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")

open_ai_agent = initialize_agent(tools,
llm,
agent=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
verbose=True)

print(open_ai_agent.run("I want to place an order. My name is John smith my phone number is 5555555555. my date of birth is 030419999 I want to order 8 large Pizzas"))
```

**Here's what I am getting back**

```
Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
```

Invoking: `place_order` with `{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'phone_number': '5555555555', 'product': 'large Pizzas', 'date_of_birth': '03041999', 'quantity': '8'}`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Documents/Code/BudtenderAI/vite-project/testagent.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(open_ai_agent.run("I want to place an order. My name is John smith my phone number is 5555555555. my date of birth is 030419999 I want to order 8 large Pizzas"))
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 487, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 292, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 286, in __call__
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1039, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 894, in _take_next_step
    observation = tool.run(
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 356, in run
    raise e
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 330, in run
    else self._run(*tool_args, **tool_kwargs)
  File "/Users/izayahhudnut/Documents/Code/BudtenderAI/vite-project/testagent.py", line 25, in _run
    place_order_response = order_three(first_name, last_name, phone_number, date_of_birth, product, quantity)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given
```

Comment: please format your question prperly, not able to understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your order_three is a class you have defined. It does not define a constructor (`__init__`). Therefore it has an empty default-constructor, which takes 1 argument (`self`). You are passing 7.

You might think that order_three should inherit a constructor from the pydantic-BaseModel. However, you redefine order_three as another class later in the code. That other class has nothing to do with `phone_number` and the other fields.